# Custom attribute is deleted on setContents() in Quill

Tags: angular, typescript, quill

I need a custom attribute in order to identify certain blocks I insert into Quill. For that, I tried to create a custom attribute like this:

`testblot.blot.ts`:

```js
import Quill from 'quill';

const Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

export class TestBlot extends Block {
    static blotName = 'testblot';
    static tagName = 'testblot';
}
```

I export it as a module in this `index.ts`:

```js
export * from './testblot.blot';
```

In my Angular component, I register the module like so:

```js
import Quill from 'quill';
import { TestBlot } from './testblot.blot';
Quill.register(TestBlot);
```

And then, I try to use the attribute in an Op I am setting:

```js
 const ops = [
            {
                attributes: {
                    testblot: true,
                },
                format: {},
                insert: title,
            },
```

However, each time I then set the content of the editor with `quillEditorInstance.setContents(deltaWithAttribute)`, the attribute is removed and `quillEditorInstance.getContents()` does not show it (but all other native attributes that Quill provides do work).

What is the reason for that behavior? What am I missing?